# Nuclear fission plant loss of coolant accident (LOCA): how bad could it get?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

In 1979 the world experienced its first severe nuclear plant accident at [Three Miles Island](http://americanhistory.si.edu/tmi/), when TMI-2 underwent a LOCA with devastating consequences for the reactor core. About 50 % of it melted and some 20 tonnes of core material ended up on the reactor vessel's floor.

However, the reactor had effectively been shut down early on in the crisis, by SCRAMming the control rods, so no more fission took place and 'only' fission product decay heat had to be dealt with.

Imagine now a LOCA where part or all of the core is no longer water cooled and the SCRAM fails (the control rod lowering mechanism fails, gets blocked or breaks).

How bad could this get, considering nuclear fission would now continue but bearing in mind also that in these PWR reactors the primary coolant is also the neutron moderator and absence of the moderator must also affect fission yield?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "severe".  Before TMI, There was the Windscale fire, the Kyshtym disaster, the SRE meltdown, The SL-1 accident, and others.  The consequences of the Kyshtym disaster were much worse than TMI, but maybe you wouldn't count it because the meltdown happened in a storage facility, not in a reactor.

Comment: @jameslarge: I guess the panic and media circus surrounding TMI-2 somewhat obscure these disasters. But that doesn't fundamentally alter the question about a SCRAM failed LOCA...

Comment: Is Chernobyl bad enough or are you waiting for someone to engineer an all out nuclear explosion for you? The latter is impossible with nuclear plants, but one can melt most of the core and partially burn it, with some of the volatile elements leaving the reactor core, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I'm not 'looking' for anything or 'waiting for someone to engineer an all out nuclear explosion for me' , what a silly way of putting things. Maybe you shouldn't assume the worst in people, you know?

Comment: @CuriousOne, technically, the Chernobyl explosion _was_ a nuclear explosion---just not a very high-yield one.  All of the energy that lifted the lid off of the reactor vessel and ejected chunks of burning core material out through the roof of the building was nuclear in origin.  In the wonderfully euphemistic language of nuclear engineering, I believe they call it a "spontaneous disassembly event."

Comment: Gert, I think @CuriousOne wanted to hint at that Chernobyl is what one would expect (and because the water vaporized, the coolant lines broke and the control rods didn't insert properly, it actually *is* very close to what you are asking).

Comment: @jameslarge: for TMI-2 they called the melting 'relocation'. They have a way with words!

Comment: @jameslarge wikipedia likens it to a [fizzle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizzle_%28nuclear_test%29)

Comment: @Gert: Sorry about the misunderstanding... what I meant was "are you asking someone to engineer the scenario of an all out nuclear explosion"? It would be a legit question to ask what the worst thing one could do to a given reactor technology would be. I don't know if Chernobyl was the worst they could have done with that particular reactor, but they certainly did something really bad there.

Comment: @jameslarge: I suppose that technically you are correct. The power excursion was caused by prompt neutrons... so does that basically count as a "fizzle" in the language of the weapons designers?

Comment: @CuriousOne; OK.

Comment: Still not sure whether a pile of molten/half molten 'corium' would not show any fission neutrons at all (even w/o a main moderator).

Answer (score 2):

As you say, in absence of moderator, light water in PWR, neutrons cannot reach thermal energy, no fission on uranium-235 appears, reactor begins not critical and it stops.  For a neutron  point of view, it is the same situation like scramming control rods.